# Using MongoDB to query selected field

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query out the data from my MongoDB database but there are some fields which I would like to omit as MongoDB will query the whole collections with id, n out.

I did this to limit the query but unfortunately only one field could be omitted but not the other which is the 'n' field. How can I omit two fields?

```
data = collection.find_one({"files_id": file_id},{"_id":0,"data":1})
```

And I also realized that my query for data has the field name (u'data') too, how can I query it so that it only returns the data? for this case it's a binary data

Example:

```
{u'data': Binary('\x00\x00\xed\x00\n\x00\x00\xd5\xa9\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x0f\xff\xf0\x00\x0b\x80\x00\x00\x00
```

Kindly assist thanks!

Comment: You can simply add fields which you don't want in output using `fieldName:0`. It will be really helpful if you provide sample document and expected output clearly.

Comment: I remove MySQL tag from your question that I think it's not related ;).

Comment: @Vishwas negative. I am only allowed to have one 0 and it's being used up by _id. Tried to do two 0 eg. _id:0, _id1:0 but there's an error

Comment: @Vishwas pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion. -> this was the error msg when it tried to do what u suggested. Expected output is '\x00\x00\xed\x00\n\x00\x00\xd5\xa9\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x0f\xff\xf0\x00\x0b\x80\x00\x00\x00 as stated above

Comment: `collection.find_one({"files_id": file_id},{"_id":0,"data":1})` - This query shoul return only `data` field. [Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)